# StreamUploadClient Error While Uploading Image to SDL Web 8

Tags: core-service, web8

While migrating images from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8, using Core Service, I came across the following error

> tridion Core Service client 2013 or earlier is used, but the 2013
>   compatibility mode is not enabled.

My bindings etc all seem correct, so I am not sure what the issue is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See documentation here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-879B67A8-71BA-4BBD-9CCE-9140B860904E

> **Compatibility break**: Uploading files to the Core Service was
>   discovered to have a security vulnerability, which was fixed in the
>   new Core Service client. However, to fix this problem in the old Core
>   Service client, uploading files has been completely disabled. If you
>   want to make uploading possible, you have two options:
>
> - Modify your
>     code to use the new Core Service client.
> - Accept the security
>     vulnerability by explicitly enabling it. SDL recommends against this,
>     but if you feel you need to do this, you can access your Content
>     Manager server, edit
>     %TRIDION_HOME%\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config, find the
>     binaryContentStorage element and add an attribute-value pair:
>     enable2013Compatibility="true" to re-enable the vulnerable upload.